# Give the ability for an ms team admin to revoke all granted permission to an app

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Hello I have an application which is asking for permissions grant with

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s/adminconsent
```

Is there any way to give the ms teams admin the ability to revoke the granted permissions which gave to my app before?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To revoke the permissions:

Navigate to https://portal.office.com/account

then click on 'App permissions' on the left panel and revoke the app permissions for the apps which you don't want anymore
Attaching a screenshot below for reference:
[image]

Comment: Details
No app description available.
Permissions
You can't revoke permission because this has been assigned to you as part of a subscription or an admin role.

Comment: If you have an admin rights then directly navigate to
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/StartboardApplicationsMenuBlade/AllApps/menuId/
and remove it there.